# Linear Least square estimate of $x^3$ given $x$ and the moments

Tags: estimation, least-squares, moments

I have been struggling to find a direction on how to proceed with the following problem. Given that $x$ is a zero mean (non-Gaussian) random variable with moments
E$(x^n)=\mu_n$.

I need to find the linear least square estimate (l.l.s.e) of $x^3$ given $x$.

If we proceed with the linear model $x^3=hx + e$, how do we then incorporate the moment information to find the l.l.s.e.

I would be grateful if someone can provide some insights to this.

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework/self-study problem.

An estimator of $h$ in your regression equation is given by  $\mathbb{E}(X^4)/\mathbb{E}(X^2)$.

To see this note that 
$$X^3 = h X + \varepsilon \Rightarrow X^4 = hX^2 + \varepsilon X \Rightarrow  \mathbb{E}(X^4) = h \mathbb{E}(X^2)+\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon X).$$
Using the usual assumption that $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon|X)=0$ this then leads to 
$$h=\mathbb{E}(X^4)/\mathbb{E}(X^2).$$

I leave it up to you to show that this estimator is identical to the least squares estimator in your regression equation, i.e. it indeed minimizes $\mathbb{E}((X^3-hX)^2)$ over all possible values of $h$.

Comment: By $(ε|X)$, you actually wanted to write $E[εX]$, right?

Comment: In regression problems you are interested in the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$, where $Y=\alpha + hX+\varepsilon$. Hence it appears more natural to make the stronger assumption $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon|X) = 0$ instead of $\mathbb{E}(X\varepsilon)=0$. The assumption is stronger since by the law of iterated expectation we still have  $\mathbb{E}(X\varepsilon) = \mathbb{E}(X \mathbb{E}(\varepsilon|X)) = 0$. However, on the other hand, from the fact that $\mathbb{E}(X\varepsilon)=0$ you may not conclude that $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon|X) = 0$.

Comment: But, it is $e$, not $ε$. If it is $e$, i.e. not the error, since X is given as zero-mean, we can say $E[eX] = eE[X] = 0$, but cannot say that $E[e|X] = 0$ since it is e

Comment: if an actual residual and no error term was meant by the op, then his question wouldnt make any sense. this is why I rewrote all variables in big letters.

Answer (score 0):

Take derivative wrt your MSE: $\frac{d}{dh}E[(x^3-hx-e)^2] = E[\frac{d}{dh}(x^3-hx-e)^2]=E[2(x^3-hx-e)(-x)] = 0$ Then,
$E[x^4]-hE[x^2]-eE[x] = 0$ and since x is zero mean, we'd have $h = \frac{E[x^4]}{E[x^2]}$.